# Alternative to angular-ui-router $urlMatcherFactory?

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently using `angular-ui-router`'s `$urlMatcherFactory` to parse variables in my URL, similar to this;

```
var params = $urlMatcherFactory.compile('#/:type/docs/articles/:id')
     .exec(location.hash, null);
```

It's pretty simple, it just parses things in the url.

I'm looking at upgrading to angular 2, though, and as such I'll have to abandon angular-ui-router. They're making a version 2 of it, but right now it doesn't work and the upgrade adapter for it doesn't work...

So is there any good alternative to angular-ui-router's `$urlMatcherFactory` for this kind of behavior? I'm not really even sure what it is called to know what to search for.